# what are the dangers of deleting .tt files in Entity Framework Database First Modelling

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using visual studio 2012 premium update 4 with Entity Framework 6.1.2 using Database first modelling. I need to change Code Generation Strategy None to Default in order to customise connection string within the code

but when I switch from None to Default I get loads of errors like

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.DbContext(string, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel)' has some invalid arguments 



Error   3   'ClassLibrary3.PHEntities' does not contain a definition for 'ContextOptions' and no extension method 'ContextOptions' accepting a first argument of type 'ClassLibrary3.PHEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\demo\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary3\Model1.Designer.cs  36  18  ClassLibrary3
```

so by deleting `Model1.Context.tt` and `Model1.tt` the errors disappeared and I can pass my customised connection string.

```
  string connection = PMCommon.PMSettings.GetEFPHConnectionString(Common.Settings.ConnectionString);
            using (var context = new PMEntities(connection))
            {
                var tests = from c in context.tblTags select c;


            }
```

I need to know are there any hidden dangers associated with this approach that could bite me in the future because I am adding a new module to a large data driven ASP.NET web application that uses loosely typed and strongly typed dataset extensively and I want to implement new stuff with Entity Framework

Comment: What in the world makes you think you need custom code generation to use a different connection string?  EF creates the DbContext as a partial class.  You need only create another partial class with the same name and your constructor that takes your connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this.  All you have to do is this.  Create a new file called PMEntities2.cs, in there do this:

```
public partial class PMEntities
{
     public PMEntities(string connnectionString) : base(connectionString){}
}
```

That's it.  You don't need to change the code generation strategy.

Comment: Thank you very much for solution. I have one problem if i give file name PMEntities2.cs then i get error at base(connectionString) object does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument but if i give file name PMEntities.cs then your solution works. Now I need to know why partial class file name PMEntities2.cs does not work and PMEntities.cs work and are there any consequences with keeping the partial class file name same as partial class

Comment: @raja - the name of the file has nothing to do with anything.  You must have been naming the class PMEntities2 as well.

Comment: Thanks again. my fault re-created the data layer project from scratch and followed your instruction and every things fine.  I want to ask does using statement handles transaction internally or I need to explicitly declare transactionscope if I am inserting data within using statement

Comment: @raja - A using statement doesn't do anything like that.  EF does implicitly crate a transaction, but that has nothing to do with using statemetns.